# Changing default media dimension in tinymce 4

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

When I try to add a direct mp4 url using insert/edit media, it by default assign the dimension of: 300x150.

How can I change this default dimension?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this setting is what you are after:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/media/#media_dimensions

The documentation is your friend for these types of issues.  Each TinyMCE plugin has a dedicated documentation page with all of its configuration options.

Comment: I had checked that documentation before posting the question here.

But I couldn't find the specific information about how to set the default dimension.